# Angular 4 to Django REST image upload

Tags: django, angular, django-models, django-rest-framework, image-uploading

i have a django REST API with a models.ImageField(), i can upload photos just fine from django itself, my problem is when im trying to do it from angular.

> .html

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label for="usr">Upload your new photo(Optional):</label> <input type="file"  accept=".jpg,.png,.jpeg" (change)="attachFile($event)">
 <br>
 <img src="{{imageSrc}}"   height="250" weight="250" alt="Image preview..." />
</div>
```

> component.ts

```
Update(form){
  let body = {
    house: 3,
    photourl: this.imageSrc
  }
  console.log(this.imageSrc)
  this.http.Post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/photos', body).subscribe( res => console.log(res))
  console.log(form)
}

attachFile(event) : void {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    let _self = this;

    reader.onload = function(e) {
      _self.imageSrc = reader.result;
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
   }
```

error is this.imageSrc is not a file, how should i get past this? What data do I need to send to an ImageField()

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/Hipo/drf-extra-fields
Well godlike library :D!

```
class HouseImSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image = Base64ImageField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = tedbnbhouseimages
        fields = ('house', 'image', 'photo')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        house = validated_data['house']
        if not validated_data['photo']:
            photo = validated_data['image']
        else:
            photo = validated_data['photo']
        houseimage = tedbnbhouseimages(
            house = house,
            photo = photo,
        )
        houseimage.save()
        return houseimage
```

photo = Imagefield from models.py, photo doesnt need to be on fields but i keep it for quick creation through DRF !